# Bootstrap left side navigation example needed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Looking for some clean and simple examples to set up a responsive left side navigation, almost exactly like Foundation uses for their ver. 4 docs page at http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/4.3.2/index.html  Needs to be able to link to pages and and also expand if there are sub pages grouped below it. Any good Bootstrap examples that do this?

Comment: Are you looking for an off-canvas example like this? http://bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/off-canvas-sidebar

Comment: yes but with something that can support sub levels like the first example.

Comment: You could integrate a Bootstrap vertical menu like this: http://bootply.com/129624

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at this example. It's a left side off-canvas menu with collapsible submenu..

**Bootstrap 3:** http://www.bootply.com/129625

```
/* collapsed sidebar styles */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .row-offcanvas {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  }
  .row-offcanvas-right
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    right: -41.6%;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    left: -41.6%;
  }
  .row-offcanvas-right.active {
    right: 41.6%;
  }
  .row-offcanvas-left.active {
    left: 41.6%;
  }
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 41.6%;
  }
  #sidebar {
    background-color:#3b3b3b;
    padding-top:0;
  }
  #sidebar .nav>li {
    color: #ddd;
    background: linear-gradient(#3E3E3E, #383838);
    border-top: 1px solid #484848;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2E2E2E;
  }
  #sidebar .nav>li:first-child {
    border-top:0;
  }
  #sidebar .nav>li>a {
    color: #ddd;
  }
  #sidebar .nav>li>a>img {
    max-width: 14px;
  }
  #sidebar .nav>li>a:hover, #sidebar .nav>li>a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: linear-gradient(#373737, #323232);
    color: #fff;  
  }
  #sidebar .nav .caret {
    border-top-color: #fff;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
  }
  #sidebar .nav a:hover .caret{
    border-top-color: #fff;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
  }
}
```

**Bootstrap 4:** https://www.codeply.com/go/JbaVzJCNLJ/bootstrap-4-off-canvas-sidebar

Comment: Another good one, thank you!

Comment: Link doesn't work :-(

Comment: Thank you but setting class="active" does not seem to work as expected