# How to add side menu that open on slide on touch devices?

Tags: javascript, cordova, sidebar, hybrid-mobile-app

Want to add side menu in my app that open on sliding finger across. Am trying for almost a week. Simply just cant find proper plugin. I read something about Intels AppFramework UI. But dont know how to integrate in my project. Just the side menu plugin. I want to apply my own css.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap left side navigation example needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22902875/bootstrap-left-side-navigation-example-needed)

Answer (score -2):

If it's a website Check Bootstrap .
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_case_menu.asp